# Why css file's styles is not applyed when used from google code repository?

Tags: css, svn, project-hosting

Here is fiddle - [silly test](http://jsfiddle.net/sauliuslx/UXH2E/2/)
Resource file test.css has these classes:

```
.parent {width:120px;display:table-row;}
.second {width: 65px; background:green;}
.cell {display:table-cell;}​
```

but they are not applyed. Seems both resources files are downloaded and javascript executed. I wonder why css is not applyed?
[image]

Comment: Your fiddle does not match your question.

Comment: @Diodeus My fiddle just demonstrates validity of my question. Can you elaborate how it doesn't much?

Comment: You have no stylesheet on your fiddle.

Comment: @Diodeus Yes I intentionally put it to resources. If you open test.css from there you'll see styles. But they not applyed.

Comment: @Diodeus Frankly, I think this question related more to `google code` tag (but it is missing at the moment) not `css`.

Comment: Drop your CSS into the CSS panel. It works there just fine.

Comment: @Diodeus. I know it :-) Fiddle is just for demonstration. If you put css link from google code to html file in your computer it won't be applyed either. I wonder why?

Comment: A sample page my be more useful than a fiddle in this case.

Comment: @Diodeus Probably. But it behaves the same trust me. If my css was on some cdn it will work, though as you see you can open it from that link.